# Get Facebook Video upload URL Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am uploading videos to Facebook Timeline successfully. But I need url for the Post. Using Video ID I can get only file url, but I need to get the Post URL so that I can also see any comments or Description attached to Video? Is it possible to get the URL of the Video Post? I am using facebook-android-sdk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this point to the file or to the page.

in "response" i get the id of the video.
I simply concact it with this String "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=" and it's the full path of the video
Code:

```
@Override
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mDialog.cancel();

         String[] temp;
         String UrlVideo = null;
            temp = response.split("\""); //the response string is like "id":"404030"} or {"error":"type of error..."}
            if( temp[1].equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
                //Video caricato e quindi anche trovato
                UrlVideo = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v="+temp[3];
                System.out.println(UrlVideo);
                //qui provvedo ad inoltrarlo al backend
            }

    }
```

i hope this help